# How to use Dlookup in Microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to use DLookup to check a text field against a database value except it returns an error when I try to do so. MemberID is the username and is being found using txtUsername field and the password is obviously password which are both retrieved from the Member table.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()

If Me.txtPassword.Value = DLookup("[Password]", "Member", "MemberID = 
Me.txtUsername.Value") Then
MsgBox "Access Granted", vbInformation, "CD Shop"
MsgBox "Welcome", vbInformation, "CD Shop"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmGymActivity"

Else
MsgBox "Please re-enter your Username and Password."
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use proper quoting and string concatenation, to make sure you're passing a string with the value you want.

```
If Me.txtPassword.Value = DLookup("[Password]", "Member", "MemberID = " & Me.txtUsername.Value) Then
```

I am assuming `MemberID` is a number.